# Convert org.w3c.dom.Node into Document

Tags: java, domdocument, xmlnode

I have a `Node` from one `Document`. I want to take that `Node` and turn it into the root node of a new `Document`.

Only way I can think of is the following:

```
Node node = someChildNodeFromDifferentDocument;

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document newDocument = builder.newDocument();
newDocument.importNode(node);
newDocument.appendChild(node);
```

This works, but I feel it is rather annoyingly verbose. Is there a less verbose/more direct way I'm not seeing, or do I just have to do it this way?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184268/org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong-document-err-a-node-is-used-in-a-different-docu

Answer (score 25):

The code did not work for me - but with some changes from this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184268/org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong-document-err-a-node-is-used-in-a-different-docu) I could get it to work as follows:

```
Node node = someChildNodeFromDifferentDocument;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document newDocument = builder.newDocument();
Node importedNode = newDocument.importNode(node, true);
newDocument.appendChild(importedNode);
```

Answer (score 6):

That looks about right to me. While it does look *generally* verbose, it certainly doesn't look significantly more verbose than other code using the DOM API. It's just an annoying API, unfortunately.

Of course, it's simpler if you've already got a `DocumentBuilder` from elsewhere - that would get rid of quite a lot of your code.

Comment: Alright, guess I just have to accept it then :p Yeah, in my actual code I have created an XmlHelper which handles the factories and such.

Comment: @Svish: Right - and if you need to do this in more than one place, you could easily write a `createDocument` method in your helper class :)

Answer (score 1):

document from Node

```
Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
```

Comment: Just wish to point out that, using `node.getOwnerDocument()` return the entire original document, not the sub portion that that `node` can represent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code:

```
String xmlResult = XMLHelper.nodeToXMLString(node);
Document docDataItem = DOMHelper.stringToDOM(xmlResult);
```

Comment: The answer should at least point where to find XMLHelper's and DOMHelper's implementations as they're not in the Java standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clone the old document using `cloneNode` and then typecast it to `Document` like below:

```java
Document newDocument = (Document) node.cloneNode(true);
```