# > and < gets converted to &gt; and &lt; while adding a xml like string in element.setTextContent()

Tags: java, xml

I have a string which looks like an XML

Ex: String sample = "<GrpHdr><MsgId>MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV</MsgId><CreDtTm>2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30</CreDtTm></GrpHdr>";

I am trying to create an XML document with an element containing the above information:

Ex:

```
<ns1:TstCode>T</ns1:TstCode>
<ns1:FType>SCF</ns1:FType>
<ns1:FileRef>220811084023</ns1:FileRef>
<ns1:RoutingInd>ALL</ns1:RoutingInd>
<ns1:FileBusDt>2022-08-11</ns1:FileBusDt>
<ns1:FIToFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd">
    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30</CreDtTm>
    </GrpHdr>
</ns1:FIToFI>
```

When I create the document for the above XML using this code:

```
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    DOMImplementation domImpl = db.getDOMImplementation();

private Document buildExampleDocumentWithNamespaces(DOMImplementation domImpl, String output) {
    Document document = domImpl.createDocument("urn:Scf:xsd:$BlkCredTrf", "ns1:BlkCredTrf", null);
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElement("ns1:TstCode")).setTextContent("T");
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElement("ns1:FType")).setTextContent("SCF");
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElement("ns1:FileRef")).setTextContent("220811084023");
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElement("ns1:RoutingInd")).setTextContent("ALL");
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElement("ns1:FileBusDt")).setTextContent("2022-08-11");
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElementNS("urn:iso:std:iso:tech:xsd","ns1:FIToFI");
    return document;
}
```

I do not have issues until this point.

When I try to add <GrpHdr><MsgId>MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV</MsgId><CreDtTm>2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30</CreDtTm></GrpHdr> as a Text content to the FIToFI tag at last, using the code:

document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(document.createElementNS("urn:iso:std:iso:tech:xsd","ns1:FIToFI").setTextContent(sample);

The XML gets created like this:

```
<ns1:TstCode>T</ns1:TstCode>
<ns1:FType>SCF</ns1:FType>
<ns1:FileRef>220811084023</ns1:FileRef>
<ns1:RoutingInd>ALL</ns1:RoutingInd>
<ns1:FileBusDt>2022-08-11</ns1:FileBusDt>
<ns1:FIToFI xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd">
    &lt;GrpHdr&gt;
        &lt;MsgId&gt;MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV&lt;/MsgId&gt;
        &lt;CreDtTm&gt;2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30&lt;/CreDtTm&gt;
    &lt;/GrpHdr&gt;
</ns1:FIToFI>
```

Please help me to create this XML without the escape characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the content is escaped is intended. When you set the text content of an element, any special character like `<` have to be escaped like `&lt;`, otherwise the text content will be interpreted as other XML content like elements or comments. That's why `setTextContent()` will escape the content for you.

When you want to add an **element** instead, you use methods like `appendChild()` with an `Element` argument. Build your elements as usual with the `createElement()` method and add them together like this:

```
Element element = document.createElementNS("urn:iso:std:iso:tech:xsd","ns1:FIToFI");
Element grpHdr = document.createElement("GrpHdr");
    
Element msgId = document.createElement("MsgId");
msgId.setTextContent("MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV");
grpHdr.appendChild(msgId);
    
Element creDtTm = document.createElement("CreDtTm");
creDtTm.setTextContent("2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30");
grpHdr.appendChild(creDtTm);
    
element.appendChild(grpHdr);
    
document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(element);
```

This will add the XML element inside the other XML element.

When you have the inner XML as a string, parse the XML string with `DocumentBuilder.parse()` (see [How to create a XML object from String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607327/how-to-create-a-xml-object-from-string-in-java)) and import the `Element` with the `Document.importNode()` method (see [org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184268/org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong-document-err-a-node-is-used-in-a-different-docu)). The code can look like this:

```
String innerXml = "<GrpHdr><MsgId[...]eDtTm></GrpHdr>";
    
Document innerDocument = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(innerXml)));
Element innerRootElement = innerDocument.getDocumentElement();
    
Node importedNode = document.importNode(innerRootElement, true);
    
element.appendChild(importedNode);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The string I posted here in the description:

<GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>MQSECJYJHRBPDTZTYNNEYXOZUPAUDEKVDFV</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2023-02-02T21:48:58.075+05:30</CreDtTm>
    </GrpHdr>

is only a sample. The real string that I want to add as a value to the element is very big. It would be cumbersome to add each element from that string individually. Is there a way I can do without escaping, like using some other method apart from setTextContent().

Comment: @Vishnu You can parse the XML code to a `Document` instance by using the `DocumentBuilder.parse()` method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607327/how-to-create-a-xml-object-from-string-in-java. Then you get the `Element` and add it to your target `Document`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Progman. You are my saviour. Your answer has solved my problem.